# Wx overlay frame how to put text or image

Tags: python, wxpython

I make a application that show me a little square of overlay with wx. and i hide it when something happen with Hide(). How i can write inside or put a image inside this box?

```
import wx


class Skill(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,xsize, ysize, xposition, yposition, color):

        style = ( wx.CLIP_CHILDREN | wx.STAY_ON_TOP | wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR |
                  wx.NO_BORDER | wx.FRAME_SHAPED  )

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, style = style)
        self.SetSize( xsize, ysize)
        self.SetPosition( (xposition,yposition))
        self.SetBackgroundColour(color)


app = wx.App()

posizioneStart = 400
skill1 = Skill (50,50,650,posizioneStart,"white")


while True:
    skill1.Show()
```

Comment: I don't rember - `wxImage`? `wxBitmap` ?

Comment: and it may need to use some `wx.Panel` to set `layout` and `Add` widgets to layout. See `wx.Frame` in [example in documentation](https://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPython%20by%20Example) which add `wx.Button but probably the same way you should add `wx.Image`

Answer (score 0):

How about that?

```
import wx


class Skill(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, xsize, ysize, xposition, yposition, color):

        style = ( wx.CLIP_CHILDREN | wx.STAY_ON_TOP | wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR |
                  wx.NO_BORDER | wx.FRAME_SHAPED  )

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, style = style)
        self.SetSize( xsize, ysize)
        self.SetPosition( (xposition,yposition))
        self.SetBackgroundColour(color)

        sb = wx.StaticText(self, style=wx.NO_BORDER)
        sb.LabelText = "Hello"
        sb.Centre()


app = wx.App()

posizioneStart = 400
skill1 = Skill (50,50,650,posizioneStart,"white")


skill1.Show()
    
app.MainLoop()
```

This puts the text "Hello" in the center of the box. Similarly, you could insert an image into the wx.StaticBox.